# Centering grid image content in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a one-row grid that is supposed to place two images on top of each other once the screen gets small enough.

[image]

It works ok, but, once the screen gets too small, the images don't get centered. In fact,the grid itself isn't centered.

[image]

I tried many approaches, but nothing seems to work.

All I want is for the two images to be centered on the screen when the screen gets too small.

All the code is inside a component. And the component itself is inside a 3 column grid (that's the one you see with the "stuff on the left" and "stuff on the right" labels).

Here's my code. I changed the background-color of each element, so I can know what's what. Also, I'm trying to center everything in many different ways:

```
<body class="justify-content-md-center" style="justify-content: center; align-items: center; background-color: blue">
            <div class="container justify-content-md-center" style="width: auto; justify-content: center; align-items: center; background-color: grey">
        <div class="container center" style="justify-content: center; background-color: yellow"> <!-- global canvas -->
            <div class="row no-gutters justify-content-md-center style="justify-content: center; background-color: red">



                <div class="col-sm" style="justify-content: center; background-color: green">
                        <img src="./images/fssFront.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm">
                    <div class="center-content">
                        <img src="./images/fssBack.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- global canvas -->
        </div>
    </body>
```

I'm pretty new to CSS, html and bootstrap. I'm sure I'm missing something.

Can you please help me out?

Thank you.

Comment: Take out `md` from the justify class. It’s centering anything bigger than that.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you can add the style property `flex-wrap: nowrap;` to the div `<div class="row no-gutters justify-content-md-center">`

The row class in bootstrap by default has the property `flex-wrap: wrap;`
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#how-it-works

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the answers.

The problem was that the component itself was inside a col-sm class, which wouldn't try to fit the screen.

Now it works with:

```
<div class="container-fluid">

                Stuff on top

                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm">
                        Stuff to the left
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            @component('components.fss') @endcomponent
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm">
                        Stuff to the right
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                Stuff below

</div>
```

Sorry for not giving you enough info in the first place.

Thank you once again.

Cheers.